# recoding level of factors with imported data

Tags: r, levels, r-factor

I have a racecallp variable, converted into a factor.

```
xrace <- as.factor(raceallp_a)

str(xrace)

[1] "AIAN and any other group"        "AIAN only"                       "Asian only"                     
[4] "Black/African American only"     "Not Ascertained"                 "Other single and multiple races"
[7] "White only"
```

I am only interested in Blacks/african only, White only, and wanted to see if its possible to combine ASIAN and AIAN only into one level. I got this so far.

```
Race1 <- factor(xrace, levels = c("Black/African American only", "White only", "Asian only"),
     labels = c("Black/African American only", "White only", "Asian only"))


table(race1)

-Black/African American
only                  
297


-White only
2021                 


-Asian only       
230
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, i.e. define the ones you want to keep and lump the rest, or use `drop` instead of `keep` if you want to do the opposite.

```r
library(tidyverse)

colours <- c("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Grey", "Orange") |> 
  fct_other(keep = c("Red", "Blue"))

levels(colours)
#> [1] "Blue"  "Red"   "Other"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>